# Решить задачу на javascript

Tags: javascript

Помогите разобрать задачу: У Аллена много денег, а именно, на счету в банке у него  долларов. По соображениям безопасности он хочет снять всю сумму наличными, мы не будет здесь описывать эти соображения. Номиналы долларовых купюр равны 1, 5, 10, 20, 100. Какое минимальное число купюр должен получить Аллен после того, как снимет все деньги?

Входные данные
Первая и единственная строка содержит одно целое число  (1≤≤109). (125)(1000000000)(43)
Выходные данные
Выведите минимальное число купюр, которые должен получить Аллен.(3)(10000000)(5)
P.S числа в скобках на входных данных и выходных - это числа которые подставляются в N и соответсвенно числа  которые должны быть на выходе(минимальное количество купюр)

Я предполагала 1)сначала сравнить n, 100 <= n <= 10000000 и если n < 100;

2) чтобы узнать количество сотен разделить n / 100; десятков - на 10;
3) а дальше не знаю как заставить компьютер считать что ему нужно подставить 20 или 10 или 5 напимер..

Comment: в массив занесите эти номиналы. потом делите исходное число на значения из массива в цикле. частное прибавляйте к результату, а остаток от деления переносите на следующую итерацию. Поскольку у вас тут все номиналы кратные, и нет например цифр 3 или 7, то задача проста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить простое решение без reduce

```js
const banknotes = [1, 5, 10, 20, 100]

const convert = (N) => {

  let min = 0

  for (let i = banknotes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    min += Math.floor(N / banknotes[i])

    N -= Math.floor(N / banknotes[i]) * banknotes[i]

  }

  return min
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! скажите пожалуйста, а i = banknotes.length -1  что означает? спасибо

Comment: @roozegrow В контексте данного цикла, i = banknotes.length -1 представляет из себя набор индексов элементов массива banknotes. Изначально i = 4, потом 3 и т.д

Comment: @roozegrow Если интересно, то логика задачи проста: на каждой итерации мы отнимает от N-ой суммы максимальное число максимальное кол-во раз.

Comment: спасибо большое )))))))

Answer (score 1):

Делите N нацело на 100, получите нужное число таких купюр. Остаток от деления делите на 20, и так далее.

```js
const data = [125, 1000000000, 43];

function test(n) {
    const nom = [100, 20, 10, 5, 1];
    return nom.reduce((acc,v) => (acc += ~~(n/v),n%=v, acc), 0);
}

data.forEach(n => console.log(n, test(n)));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Прояснилось))

Comment: @roozegrow вам и в правду понятная запись вида `acc += ~~(n/v)`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko аххах :D

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ему может и да, а вот мне кстати несовсем. Можете рассказать,пожалуйста, как это работает или поделиться ссылкой на объяснение? спасибо!

Comment: Нет , пока есть предположение  и помощь  в словесной интерпритации. Буду разбираться))))
возможно acc это числа входных данных , v числа из массива  в функции тест

Comment: @letUser http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice

Comment: спасибо за ссылку!!!!!

Comment: @teran я бы переписал на более дружелюбный код :) Все таки это не код-гольф :D Хотя, уже есть ответ с более человечным кодом. Оставляйте, будет круто!